# footer moves up when window height is decrease in my code how can I force it to be below all other contents?

Tags: css

I looked on google and stack-over-flow for hours and their advice work on their code examples but for some reason I can't get the footer to stay below my contents in my code when

I decrease the windows height the footer moves above over the contents. How can I get it to be below all the contents of the page regardless if the window height size is reduced?

**code example**

```html
<style>
  body{
  color: white;
  font-family: raleway;
  background-color: black;
}

.nav-bar{
  background-color: black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 8px;
  right: 8px;
}

.nav-bar a{
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-bar #sign-up,#login{
  float: right;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.image-container{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 500px;
  background: url('http://www.dumpaday.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/photos-1-25.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: gray;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 8px;
  right: 8px;
}

.image-container .text-box{
  /*background-color: red;*/

  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 175px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.image-container .text-box #title-text{
  text-align: center;
}

.image-container .text-box h3{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.image-container .text-box #model-option{
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.image-container .options-container{
  padding: 5px;
  /*background-color: gold;*/
  width: 158px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.intro-container{
 /*background-color: red;*/
}

.intro-container .text-box{
 /*background-color: gold;*/
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.intro-container .text-box #welcome-title{
  text-align: center;
}

.intro-container .text-box #details{
  text-align: center;
}

footer{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
color: white;
font-family: raleway;
 border-top: 1px solid white;
}
</style>

<div class='nav-bar'>
  <a id='sign-up' href='#'>Signup</a>
  <a id='login' href='#'>Login</a>
</div><!--</nav-bar>-->

<div class='image-container'>
  <div class='text-box'>
    <h1 id='title-text'>BlaBlablablabla</h1>
    
<div class='options-container'>
    <h3 id='model-option'>Model</h3>
    <h3 id='client-option'>Client</h3>
    </div><!--</options-container>-->
  
  </div><!--</text-box>-->
</div><!--</image-container>-->

<div class='intro-container'>
  <div class='text-box'>
  <h2 id='welcome-title'>Radom</h2>
    <p id='details'>blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla</p>
  </div><!--<text-box>-->
</div><!--</intro-container>-->
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Comment: add `position:relative` to body ... add also `padding-bottom:50px` to body

Comment: Thanks for your reply Temani Afif but your advice did not work I need the footer to always be below all the other contents at all times regardless on the window's height size.

Comment: and this is what will happen with my code :) here is : https://jsfiddle.net/m76t55jk/1/

Comment: Thanks for your reply Temani Afif it is now below :) but :( how can I manipulate the footers height? It gets bigger when I zoom out of the page i'm trying to make the footers height stay a certain height regardless of page zoom out.

Answer (score 0):

use position:fixed; instead of position:absolute;

```
    position: fixed;
```

This will keep it where you place it.

Comment: thanks for your reply Sheepherder but I can't use that because it gives the same effect I need it to be below all the contents of the page regardless of the windows height size.